# Set this countdown timer to specific time

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I have a Javascript code for a countdown timer on a date. I want to use this code in a online shop order process. However I don't want to edit the date every day manually. I want that the timer counts everyday to the same target time.

Note: the variable responsible for that is: deadline

```
function updateTimer(deadline){
      var time = deadline - new Date();
      return {
        'days': Math.floor( time/(1000*60*60*24) ),
        'hours': Math.floor( (time/(1000*60*60)) % 24 ),
        'minutes': Math.floor( (time/1000/60) % 60 ),
        'seconds': Math.floor( (time/1000) % 60 ),
        'total' : time
      };
    }


    function animateClock(span){
      span.className = "turn";
      setTimeout(function(){
        span.className = "";
      },700);
    }

    function startTimer(id, deadline){
      var timerInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var timer = updateTimer(deadline);

        clock.innerHTML = '<span>' + timer.days + '</span>'
                        + '<span>' + timer.hours + '</span>'
                        + '<span>' + timer.minutes + '</span>'
                        + '<span>' + timer.seconds + '</span>';

        //animations
        var spans = clock.getElementsByTagName("span");
        animateClock(spans[3]);
        if(timer.seconds == 59) animateClock(spans[2]);
        if(timer.minutes == 59 && timer.seconds == 59) animateClock(spans[1]);
        if(timer.hours == 23 && timer.minutes == 59 && timer.seconds == 59) animateClock(spans[0]);

        //check for end of timer
        if(timer.total < 1){
          clearInterval(timerInterval);
          clock.innerHTML = '<span>0</span><span>0</span><span>0</span><span>0</span>';
        }


      }, 1000);
    }


    window.onload = function(){
      var deadline = new Date("august 26, 2017 17:15:00");
      startTimer("clock", deadline);
    };
```

Comment: Hint: what does `new Date()` (with no parameters) give you?

Comment: sorry but I'm not the coder of this script, so I don't really know much of these events.I'm a newbie

Comment: I've tried the event without parameters and it gave me the current date!